# Text inside div animation

Tags: html, css

So I've got some text inside a < div > tag and I want it to animate. Now I want the text to start from a low opacity and then have the opacity increase as time passes. I've found an easy way for it to DECREASE but I find it near impossible to make it start from that state and  do it backwards since if I change the opacity attribute on my < p > the < div > will always treat the < p > at that opacity.

My code (chrome):

```
@-webkit-keyframes opac /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity:0.4}
25%  {opacity:0.4}
50%  {opacity:0.7}
75%  {opacity:0.8}
100% {opacity:1}
}

.doge1:hover {
animation-name: opac;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-play-state: running;
/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name: opac;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="doge1">
    <p>
    Transitions in CSS are applied to an element and specify that when a property changes it should do so gradually over a period of time. Animations are different. When applied, they just run and do their thing. They offer more fine-grained control as you can control different stops of the animations.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the desired effect? To have it start at `opacity: .4`, and animate to `opacity: 1` when the user hovers over?

Comment: Are any of the answers below helpful? If so, will you accept one? If not, please leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

This? [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/eNamOton/1/edit)

```
.doge1 > p {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opac /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity:0.4}
25%  {opacity:0.4}
50%  {opacity:0.7}
75%  {opacity:0.8}
100% {opacity:1}
}

.doge1:hover > p {
animation-name: opac;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-play-state: running;
/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name: opac;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your desired effect, but you could achieve this a little easier with:

```
.doge1 {
    opacity: .4;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.doge1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JFA7g/